# How to run ant from an Eclipse plugin, send output to an Eclipse console, and capture the build result (success/failure)?

Tags: eclipse, ant, console

From within an Eclipse plugin, I'd like to run an Ant build script.  I also want to display the Ant output to the user, by displaying it in an Eclipse console.  Finally, I also want to wait for the Ant build to be finished, and capture the result: did the build succeed or fail?

I found three ways to run an Ant script from eclipse:

- Instantiate an `org.eclipse.ant.core.AntRunner`, call some setters and call `run()` or `run(IProgressMonitor)`.  The result is either normal termination (indicating success), or a CoreException with an `IStatus` containing a `BuildException` (indicating failure), or else something else went wrong.  However, I don't see the Ant output anywhere.
- Instantiate an `org.eclipse.ant.core.AntRunner` and call `run(Object)`, passing a `String[]` containing the command line arguments.  The result is either normal termination (indication success), or an `InvocationTargetException` (indicating failure), or else something else went wrong.  The Ant output is sent to Eclipse's stdout, it seems; it is not visible in Eclipse itself.
- Call `DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager()`, then on that call `getLaunchConfigurationType(IAntLaunchConfigurationConstants.ID_ANT_BUILDER_LAUNCH_CONFIGURATION_TYPE)`, then on that set attribute `"org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_LOCATION"` to the build file name (and attribute `DebugPlugin.ATTR_CAPTURE_OUTPUT` to true) and finally call `launch()`.  The Ant output is shown in an Eclipse console, but I have no idea how to capture the build result (success/failure) in my code.  Or how to wait for termination of the launch, even.

Is there any way to have *both* console output *and* capture the result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit 05/16/2016** @Lii alerted me to the fact that any output between the `ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy#launch` call and when the `IStreamListener` is appended will be lost. He made a contribution to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37243778/152640).

**Original Answer**
I realize this is an old post, but I was able to do exactly what you want in one of my plugins. If it doesn't help you at this point, maybe it will help someone else. I originally did this in 3.2, but it has been updated for 3.6 API changes...

```java
// show the console
final IWorkbenchPage activePage = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
        .getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
        .getActivePage();
activePage.showView(IConsoleConstants.ID_CONSOLE_VIEW);

// let launch manager handle ant script so output is directed to Console view
final ILaunchManager manager = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager();
ILaunchConfigurationType type = manager.getLaunchConfigurationType(IAntLaunchConstants.ID_ANT_LAUNCH_CONFIGURATION_TYPE);
final ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy workingCopy = type.newInstance(null, [*** GIVE YOUR LAUNCHER A NAME ***]);
workingCopy.setAttribute(ILaunchManager.ATTR_PRIVATE, true);
workingCopy.setAttribute(IExternalToolConstants.ATTR_LOCATION, [*** PATH TO ANT SCRIPT HERE ***]);
final ILaunch launch = workingCopy.launch(ILaunchManager.RUN_MODE, null);
// make sure the build doesnt fail
final boolean[] buildSucceeded = new boolean[] { true };
((AntProcess) launch.getProcesses()[0]).getStreamsProxy()
        .getErrorStreamMonitor()
        .addListener(new IStreamListener() {
            @Override
            public void streamAppended(String text, IStreamMonitor monitor) {
                if (text.indexOf("BUILD FAILED") > -1) {
                    buildSucceeded[0] = false;
                }
            }
        });
// wait for the launch (ant build) to complete
manager.addLaunchListener(new ILaunchesListener2() {
    public void launchesTerminated(ILaunch[] launches) {
        boolean patchSuccess = false;
        try {
            if (!buildSucceeded[0]) {
                throw new Exception("Build FAILED!");
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < launches.length; i++) {
                if (launches[i].equals(launch)
                        && buildSucceeded[0]
                        && !((IProgressMonitor) launches[i].getProcesses()[0]).isCanceled()) {
                    [*** DO YOUR THING... ***]
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            [*** DO YOUR THING... ***]
        } finally {
            // get rid of this listener
            manager.removeLaunchListener(this);
            [*** DO YOUR THING... ***]
        }
    }

    public void launchesAdded(ILaunch[] launches) {
    }

    public void launchesChanged(ILaunch[] launches) {
    }

    public void launchesRemoved(ILaunch[] launches) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Shortly after I posted this question, the project for which I was going to use it was canceled.  Since this is the most complete reply that actually worked for you, I'm marking this as the answer.

Comment: The upvote drew my attention back to this old answer. Still working well in 4.2 (Juno).

Comment: I [posted an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37243778/452775) about a problem with lost output that I had with this solution. I think output can happen after `workingCopy.launch(...)` but before `.addListener(new IStreamListener() { ... })`. That output never reaches the listener. It might be a good idea to add a note about that to your answer, other peoply might also spend a long time being confused about why their stream listeners are not called.

Comment: Thanks for the addition @Lii

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add one thing to [happytime harry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364247/how-to-run-ant-from-an-eclipse-plugin-send-output-to-an-eclipse-console-and-ca#3961526).

Sometimes the first writes to the stream happens before the stream listener is added. Then `streamAppended` on the listener is never called for those writes so output is lost.

See for example this [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=121454). I think happytime harry's solution might have this problem. I myself registered my stream listener in `ILaunchListener.launchChanged` and this happened 4/5 times.

If one wants to be sure to get all the output from a stream then the `IStreamMonitor.getContents` method can be used to fetch the output that happened before the listener got added.

The following is an attempt on a utility method that handles this. It is based on the code in [`ProcessConsole`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.debug.git/tree/org.eclipse.debug.ui/ui/org/eclipse/debug/internal/ui/views/console/ProcessConsole.java).

```java
/**
 * Adds listener to monitor, and calls listener with any content monitor already has.
 * NOTE: This methods synchronises on monitor while listener is called. Listener may
 * not wait on any thread that waits for monitors monitor, what would result in dead-lock.
 */
public static void addAndNotifyStreamListener(IStreamMonitor monitor, IStreamListener listener) {
    // Synchronise on monitor to prevent writes to stream while we are adding listener.
    // It's weird to synchronise on monitor because that's a shared object, but that's 
    // what ProcessConsole does.  
    synchronized (monitor) {
        String contents = monitor.getContents();
        if (!contents.isEmpty()) {
            // Call to unknown code while synchronising on monitor. This is dead-lock prone!
            // Listener must not wait for other threads that are waiting in line to 
            // synchronise on monitor.
            listener.streamAppended(contents, monitor);
        }
        monitor.addListener(listener);
    }
}
```

PS: There is some weird stuff going on in `ProcessConsole.java`. Why is the content buffering switched of from the `ProcessConsole.StreamListener` constructor?! If the `ProcessConsole.StreamListener` runs before this one maybe this solution doesn't work.